# How does boost bind work behind the scenes in general?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind

Without spending a long time reviewing the boost source code, could someone give me a quick rundown of how boost bind is implemented?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I like this piece of the `bind` source:

```
template<class R, class F, class L> class bind_t
{
public:

    typedef bind_t this_type;

    bind_t(F f, L const & l): f_(f), l_(l) {}

#define BOOST_BIND_RETURN return
#include <boost/bind/bind_template.hpp>
#undef BOOST_BIND_RETURN

};
```

Tells you almost all you need to know, really.

The `bind_template` header expands to a list of inline `operator()` definitions. For example, the simplest:

```
result_type operator()()
{
    list0 a;
    BOOST_BIND_RETURN l_(type<result_type>(), f_, a, 0);
}
```

We can see the `BOOST_BIND_RETURN` macro expands to `return` at this point so the line is more like `return l_(type...)`.

The one parameter version is here:

```
template<class A1> result_type operator()(A1 & a1)
{
    list1<A1 &> a(a1);
    BOOST_BIND_RETURN l_(type<result_type>(), f_, a, 0);
}
```

It's pretty similar.

The `listN` classes are wrappers for the parameter lists. There is a lot of deep magic going on here that I don't really understand too much though. They have also overloaded `operator()` that calls the mysterious `unwrap` function. Ignoring some compiler specific overloads, it doesn't do a lot:

```
// unwrap

template<class F> inline F & unwrap(F * f, long)
{
    return *f;
}

template<class F> inline F & unwrap(reference_wrapper<F> * f, int)
{
    return f->get();
}

template<class F> inline F & unwrap(reference_wrapper<F> const * f, int)
{
    return f->get();
}
```

The naming convention seems to be: `F` is the type of the function parameter to `bind`. `R` is the return type. `L` tends to be a list of parameter types. There are also a lot of complications because there are no less than nine overloads for different numbers of parameters. Best not to dwell on that too much.

Comment: this does not seem simple to me...

why is the `#define BOOST_BIND_RETURN return` necessary ?

why not just return ?

Comment: I still do not get it. What call the constructor to `bind_t`?

Comment: @Ha11owed because that way they can use the header for templates that have no return value!

Answer (score 2):

By the way, if `bind_t` is collapsed and simplified by including `boost/bind/bind_template.hpp` , it becomes easier to understand like the following :

```
template<class R, class F, class L> 
class bind_t
{
    public:

        typedef bind_t this_type;

        bind_t(F f, L const & l): f_(f), l_(l) {}

        typedef typename result_traits<R, F>::type result_type;
        ...
        template<class A1> 
            result_type operator()(A1 & a1)
            {
                list1<A1 &> a(a1);
                return l_(type<result_type>(), f_, a, 0);
            }
    private:
        F f_;
        L l_;

};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a template class that declares a member variable for the arguments you want to bind and overloads () for the rest of the arguments.