# Why can a C++ function type alias be used to pass a lambda to a function?

Tags: c++

Have a look at the code example listed below, I tested it with Compiler explorer (using gcc and clang) and it works and prints out the (expected) output of 200.

What I am trying to figure out: why exactly is this valid C++. Or is it not?

Here, I'm using the `using` keyword to define an alias (instead of a `typedef`) for the function type `ft`, which describes functions that take an `int` as argument and return an `int` (`ft` is a function type, not a function pointer type!). The equivalent `typedef` syntax is `typedef int ft(int);`. Since the C++ standard says that for every `typedef` there is an equivalent form using the `using` syntax, it is clear that `using ft = int(int)` is a well-defined way to specify this function type.

Now comes the interesting part: I use the type `ft` to specify the argument type of another function (`print_it`), and then call it, passing a lambda function. My question is: where/how does the C++ standard say that this should actually work? I think it is a wonderfully simple way to pass lambdas around. That this works is not clear to me, as a lambda is really a functor, not a function in the strict sense. So I think it is not clear that this lambda matches the type `ft` and therefore can be passed to `print_it` (if `ft` was defined to be `std::function<int(int)>` it would be clear though).

The code example:

```
#include <iostream>

using ft = int(int);

void print_it (ft f, int a)
{
    std::cout << f(a) << std::endl;
}

int main ()
{
    auto my_lambda = [] (int a) -> int { return 2 * a; };

    print_it (my_lambda, 100);

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: `ft` decays to a function pointer and a non capturing lambda can be converted to a function pointer.

Comment: @NathanOliver make that an answer, it's the exact answer to the question (I think).

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746744/passing-capturing-lambda-as-function-pointer and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997237/c11-lambdas-to-function-pointer

Comment: OP is looking for a standards qoute though i think: `where/how does the C++ standard say that this should actually work?`

Comment: @lorro There should be plenty of duplicates.  Found 2ish

Comment: @NathanOliver: I have to look up the details, but the hint regarding the decay is the precise information I was missing to wrap my head around it. Thanks.

Comment: @sperber No problem. https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.fct#5 covers why `ft` becomes a function pointer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> My question is: where/how does the C++ standard say that this should actually work?

This is specified in [[expr.prim.lambda.closure]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.prim.lambda.closure#7), which specifies that a lambda's closure type has a conversion function to a function pointer type matching the lambda's parameter and return types if the lambda is non-generic and doesn't have any capture. Calling through this function pointer basically behaves as if the lambda body was just a normal function to which the pointer points, which is possible because there are no captures which could give the lambda a state that a normal function can't have.

This applies here and you are using the conversion operator to implicitly convert the lambda object to a function pointer when passing it to `print_it`. This works since the lambda's parameter and return type matches the `ft` type and a function type used as type of a function parameter is adjusted to a pointer-to-function type instead. (See [[dcl.fct]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.fct#5.sentence-3) for the last part.)

For generic lambdas there is a conversion function template (see the following standard paragraph). For lambdas with a capture there is no such conversion function and therefore this wouldn't work for them.

Answer (score 1):

This only works because your lambda does not capture. A capture-less lambda can be converted to a C-style function pointer but a captureing lambda cannot.