# member function as callback

Tags: callback, member

I would like to pass  a member function of an instantiated object to another function. Example code is below. I am open for any strategy that works, including calling functional() from another function inside memberfuncpointertestclass using something like lambda or std::bind. Please note that I did not understand most of the threads I found with google about lambda or std::bind, so please, if possible, keep it simple. Also note that my cluster does not have C++ 11 and I would like to keep functional() as simple as it is. Thank you!

```
int functional( int (*testmem)(int arg) )
{
    int a = 4;
    int b = testmem(a);
    return b;
}

class memberfuncpointertestclass
{
public:
    int parm;
    int member( int arg )
    {
        return(arg + parm);
    }
};

void funcpointertest()
{
    memberfuncpointertestclass a;
    a.parm = 3;

    int (*testf)(int) = &a.member;

    std::cout << functional(testf);
}

int main()
{
    funcpointertest();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not just pass the object and call the method?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot invoke a method on an object without an instance to refer to. So, you need to pass in both the instance as well as the method you want to invoke.

Try changing `functional` to:

```
template <typename T, typename M>
int functional(T *obj, M method)
{
    int a = 4;
    int b = (obj->*(method))(a);
    return b;
}
```

And your `funcpointertest` to:

```
void funcpointertest()
{
    memberfuncpointertestclass a;
    a.parm = 3;

    std::cout << functional(&a, &memberfuncpointertestclass::member);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for `std::function`, a polymorphic function wrapper. Pass to functional(...) such a function object:

```
#include <functional>

typedef std::tr1::function<int(int)> CallbackFunction;

int functional(CallbackFunction testmem)
{
    int a = 4;
    int b = testmem(a);
    return b;
}
```

then use `std::bind` to create a function object of the same type that wraps memberfuncpointertestclass::method() of instance a:

```
void funcpointertest()
{
    memberfuncpointertestclass a;
    a.parm = 3;

    CallbackFunction testf = std::bind(&memberfuncpointertestclass::member, &a, std::placeholders::_1);

    std::cout << functional(testf);
}
```

Check [this item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527413/how-boostfunction-and-boostbind-work) for more details.