# Is there a way to attach a callback to C++ object member?

Tags: c++

Context: My C++ experience is about 3/10, so bear with me.

I'm curious to know if it's possible to attach a read callback function to a C++ object member, so that when I assign:

```
var = object.member;
```

this calls a callback, which updates member before returning it. I can achieve the same end by

```
...
var = object.GetMemberVal();
...
int FooClass::GetMemberVal()
{
    // update member value
    return this->member;
}
```

But *val = object.member;* (no parens) is a bit cleaner and seems closer to the spirit of object-orientedness... I think.

I think [member function as callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16045892/member-function-as-callback) may be related, but I'm not totally following.

Whether this is a good idea or not may be up for debate, I'm just interested to know if it's possible.

Comment: What about `object.member = var`? What should happen in this case?

Comment: Whel , you can , but it's a hack and it's not practical, you can create a class that will overload the `=` operator and call a callback for the left member or the right member. You also need to know the `member` to which instance it belongs ...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct, you might want to use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) for this:

```
auto myGetMemberVal = std::bind(&FooClass::GetMemberVal, object);

// ...

int value = myGetMemberVal();  // Actually calls object.GetMemberVal()
```

The `std::bind` function creates a callable object, which will call the function you tell it to.

Answer (score 0):

Borland C++ Builder had something like this called a `property` but it isn't a standard C++ feature.

Using standard C++ you can create a template class that wraps the member and implements at least these functions:

- `operator T` : for reading the value. T is the type of the member (e.g. int)
- `operator =` : for writing the value

For simple built in types it's fairly simple.

If you want the member to be just an `int` and you only want direct access to it (no wrappers), then you can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help your cause:

```
#include <iostream>


typedef int (*func)(int,int);

int f1(int x,int y)
{
  return x+y;
}

class A{

  int _x;
  int _y;
  int _z;

  public:

  A(int num1,int num2):_y(num1),_z(num2){}

  void set ( int (*f)(int x,int y))
  {
    _x = (*f)(_y,_z);
  }

  int get ()
  {
    return _x;
  }

};

int main()
{
  A instance(11,1);
  instance.set(f1);
  std::cout<<instance.get()<<std::endl;
}
```