# Is it possible to boost::bind to a member function of a known class but a (yet) unknown object?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, bind, dispatch

I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527413/how-boostfunction-and-boostbind-work) about how boost:bind works, especially that it - besides other things - generates something like this:

```
struct unspecified_type
{
  ... some members ...
  return_type operator()(int i) const { return instance->*&klass::member(0, i);
}
```

Now, I'm looking for something which would allow to add an additional indirection to the instance pointer, so that it ultimatively would look like this:

```
struct unspecified_type
{
  ... some members ...
  return_type operator()(int i) const { return (*p_instance)->*&klass::member(0, i);
}
```

and could be used like

```
MyClass* pmc;
auto mfp = boost::bind(&MyClass::some_func, &pmc);
pmc = new MyClass();
mfp();
pmc = new MyClass();
mfp();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `std::bind` and `std::ref`, or their boost equivalent (but since you are using C++11, you may want to use standard classes and functions). So given this class:

```
#include <iostream>

struct MyClass
{
    int x;
    MyClass(int x_) : x(x_) { }
    void some_func()
    {
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
};
```

You could pass the pointer on which the member function is to be invoked wrapped in an `std::reference_wrapper`. Also, avoid using `new` (and `delete`!) and prefer using smart pointers for modeling object ownership:

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::shared_ptr<MyClass> pmc;
    auto mfp = std::bind(&MyClass::some_func, std::ref(pmc));

    pmc = std::make_shared<MyClass>(42);
    mfp();

    pmc = std::make_shared<MyClass>(1729);
    mfp();
}
```

Here is a [**live example**](http://ideone.com/ugoRD7).

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can extend `boost::bind` (but not `std::bind`) using `get_pointer` function:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
struct MyClass
{
  void some_func()
  {}
};

namespace boost
{
  template<class T>
  T *get_pointer(T **t)
  {
    return *t;
  }
}

int main()
{
  MyClass *pmc;
  auto mfp = boost::bind(&MyClass::some_func, &pmc);
  pmc = new MyClass();
  mfp();
  pmc = new MyClass();
  mfp();
}
```

Comment: Hi Igor. That's what I was first thinking about (without knowing really much about it) and i think it might be a more intuitive solution from an explorative approach, though, I favor the one from Andy because its semantics seem to be more standard like and use existing types but will keep yours in mind for events where everything else doesn't help.