# Clarification on the use of `boost::bind` and `this`

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I was making some modifications to a `boost::asio` project today and I ran into a confusing compilation error when attempting to pass a bound function into an async call.

I have spent hours fiddling with this code, so I suspect I am missing something stupid.  I would appreciate anyone who can point out where I am going wrong.

```
error: no match for call to ‘(boost::_mfi::mf3<void, ClientServerManager, 
    const MCServer&, boost::shared_ptr<Connection>, 
    const boost::system::error_code&>) (ClientServerManager*&, 
    MCServer&, boost::shared_ptr<Connection>&, 
    const MCServer&)’
```

Notice that `const MCServer&` appears twice?  That isn't how my bind statement is written:

```
void ClientServerManager::onConnect(const MCServer& server_info, 
    boost::shared_ptr<Connection> con,
    const boost::system::error_code& err,
    tcp::resolver::iterator i) {

    // Instruct utility to do some work, and call our function when complete.
    con->statusPing(
        boost::bind( // <-- OFFENDING CODE
            &ClientServerManager::onPingCompletion,
            this,
            server_info,
            con,  // shared_ptr to connection (maintains scope)
            boost::asio::placeholders::error // in case of a downstream failure
        )
    );
}
```

In the Connection header `statusPing(...)` is defined as follows:

```
void statusPing(boost::function<
    void(
        MCServer&, boost::shared_ptr<Connection>, 
        const boost::system::error_code&
    )>);
```

The handler eventually to be called:

```
void ClientServerManager::onPingCompletion(
    const MCServer& server_info, 
    boost::shared_ptr<Connection>,     
    const boost::system::error_code& err){
    // Use the results to drive some function...
}
```

**Background:**

- I have a class which iterates through a list of servers and opens
  short-lived connections with them to make sure they are operating
  properly.
- The class uses a utility, `Connection` which inherits
  `boost::enable_shared_from_this.`  Therefore, I call a function, `Connection::create(..)` to grab a `boost::shared_ptr` to start work with.   When any async calls are made, this pointer has to be passed to keep the connection in scope.
- In this instance after the connection is successfully established, I want to pass execution to `Connection` such that it can execute some tasks, and I want it to call a handle once those tasks are complete. **I cannot get boost::bind to compile properly in this case.**
- Now the issue I am having is that the `boost::bind` might be linked to the use of the `boost::asio::placeholders::error` template.

**The full output follows:**

```
   g++ -std=c++0x -DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK -I/home/donald/Desktop/workspace/MCProxy/Debug/ -O3 -march=corei7-avx -g1 -w -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/ClientServerManager.d" -MT"src/ClientServerManager.d" -o "src/ClientServerManager.o" "../src/ClientServerManager.cpp"
In file included from ....
/boost/bind/bind.hpp: In instantiation of ‘void boost::_bi::list4<A1, A2, A3, A4>::operator()(boost::_bi::type<void>, F&, A&, int) [with F = boost::_mfi::mf3<void, ClientServerManager, const MCServer&, boost::shared_ptr<Connection>, const boost::system::error_code&>; A = boost::_bi::list3<const MCServer&, boost::shared_ptr<Connection>&, const boost::system::error_code&>; A1 = boost::_bi::value<ClientServerManager*>; A2 = boost::_bi::value<MCServer>; A3 = boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<Connection> >; A4 = boost::arg<1> (*)()]’:
/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:116:59:   required from ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::result_type boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::operator()(A1&, A2&, A3&) [with A1 = const MCServer; A2 = boost::shared_ptr<Connection>; A3 = const boost::system::error_code; R = void; F = boost::_mfi::mf3<void, ClientServerManager, const MCServer&, boost::shared_ptr<Connection>, const boost::system::error_code&>; L = boost::_bi::list4<boost::_bi::value<ClientServerManager*>, boost::_bi::value<MCServer>, boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<Connection> >, boost::arg<1> (*)()>; boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::result_type = void]’
/boost/function/function_template.hpp:153:11:   required from ‘static void boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker3<FunctionObj, R, T0, T1, T2>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, T0, T1, T2) [with FunctionObj = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf3<void, ClientServerManager, const MCServer&, boost::shared_ptr<Connection>, const boost::system::error_code&>, boost::_bi::list4<boost::_bi::value<ClientServerManager*>, boost::_bi::value<MCServer>, boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<Connection> >, boost::arg<1> (*)()> >; R = void; T0 = const MCServer&; T1 = boost::shared_ptr<Connection>; T2 = const boost::system::error_code&]’
/boost/function/function_template.hpp:934:60:   required from ‘void boost::function3<R, T1, T2, T3>::assign_to(Functor) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf3<void, ClientServerManager, const MCServer&, boost::shared_ptr<Connection>, const boost::system::error_code&>, boost::_bi::list4<boost::_bi::value<ClientServerManager*>, boost::_bi::value<MCServer>, boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<Connection> >, boost::arg<1> (*)()> >; R = void; T0 = const MCServer&; T1 = boost::shared_ptr<Connection>; T2 = const boost::system::error_code&]’
/boost/function/function_template.hpp:722:7:   required from ‘boost::function3<R, T1, T2, T3>::function3(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf3<void, ClientServerManager, const MCServer&, boost::shared_ptr<Connection>, const boost::system::error_code&>, boost::_bi::list4<boost::_bi::value<ClientServerManager*>, boost::_bi::value<MCServer>, boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<Connection> >, boost::arg<1> (*)()> >; R = void; T0 = const MCServer&; T1 = boost::shared_ptr<Connection>; T2 = const boost::system::error_code&; typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type = int]’
/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1071:16:   required from ‘boost::function<R(T0, T1, T2)>::function(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf3<void, ClientServerManager, const MCServer&, boost::shared_ptr<Connection>, const boost::system::error_code&>, boost::_bi::list4<boost::_bi::value<ClientServerManager*>, boost::_bi::value<MCServer>, boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<Connection> >, boost::arg<1> (*)()> >; R = void; T0 = const MCServer&; T1 = boost::shared_ptr<Connection>; T2 = const boost::system::error_code&; typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type = int]’
../src/ClientServerManager.cpp:90:3:   required from here
/boost/bind/bind.hpp:457:9: error: no match for call to ‘(boost::_mfi::mf3<void, ClientServerManager, const MCServer&, boost::shared_ptr<Connection>, const boost::system::error_code&>) (ClientServerManager*&, MCServer&, boost::shared_ptr<Connection>&, const MCServer&)’
In file included ....
/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:366:85: note: candidates are:
/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:391:7: note: R boost::_mfi::mf3<R, T, A1, A2, A3>::operator()(T*, A1, A2, A3) const [with R = void; T = ClientServerManager; A1 = const MCServer&; A2 = boost::shared_ptr<Connection>; A3 = const boost::system::error_code&]
/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:391:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 4 from ‘const MCServer’ to ‘const boost::system::error_code&’
/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:396:25: note: template<class U> R boost::_mfi::mf3::operator()(U&, A1, A2, A3) const [with U = U; R = void; T = ClientServerManager; A1 = const MCServer&; A2 = boost::shared_ptr<Connection>; A3 = const boost::system::error_code&]
/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:396:25: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included ....
/boost/bind/bind.hpp:457:9: note:   cannot convert ‘(& a)->boost::_bi::list3<A1, A2, A3>::operator[]<const MCServer&, boost::shared_ptr<Connection>&, const boost::system::error_code&>(boost::_bi::storage4<A1, A2, A3, boost::arg<I> (*)()>::a4_<boost::_bi::value<ClientServerManager*>, boost::_bi::value<MCServer>, boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<Connection> >, 1>)’ (type ‘const MCServer’) to type ‘const boost::system::error_code&’
In file included ....
/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:404:25: note: template<class U> R boost::_mfi::mf3::operator()(const U&, A1, A2, A3) const [with U = U; R = void; T = ClientServerManager; A1 = const MCServer&; A2 = boost::shared_ptr<Connection>; A3 = const boost::system::error_code&]
/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:404:25: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included ....
/boost/bind/bind.hpp:457:9: note:   cannot convert ‘(& a)->boost::_bi::list3<A1, A2, A3>::operator[]<const MCServer&, boost::shared_ptr<Connection>&, const boost::system::error_code&>(boost::_bi::storage4<A1, A2, A3, boost::arg<I> (*)()>::a4_<boost::_bi::value<ClientServerManager*>, boost::_bi::value<MCServer>, boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<Connection> >, 1>)’ (type ‘const MCServer’) to type ‘const boost::system::error_code&’
In file included from ....
/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:412:7: note: R boost::_mfi::mf3<R, T, A1, A2, A3>::operator()(T&, A1, A2, A3) const [with R = void; T = ClientServerManager; A1 = const MCServer&; A2 = boost::shared_ptr<Connection>; A3 = const boost::system::error_code&]
/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:412:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘ClientServerManager*’ to ‘ClientServerManager&’
```

---

**Edit: (`boost::function<void(...)>` -> `boost::function<void()>`)**

Per suggestion, I changed the `Connection` function to read `void statusPing(boost::function<void()>);` as the parameters are bound in.  This change yields a different error:

```
g++ -std=c++0x -DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK -I/home/donald/Desktop/workspace/MCProxy/Debug/ -O3 -march=corei7-avx -g1 -w -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/ClientServerManager.d" -MT"src/ClientServerManager.d" -o "src/ClientServerManager.o" "../src/ClientServerManager.cpp"
In file included from ....
/boost/bind/bind.hpp: In instantiation of ‘void boost::_bi::list4<A1, A2, A3, A4>::operator()(boost::_bi::type<void>, F&, A&, int) [with F = boost::_mfi::mf3<void, ClientServerManager, const MCServer&, boost::shared_ptr<Connection>&, const boost::system::error_code&>; A = boost::_bi::list0; A1 = boost::_bi::value<ClientServerManager*>; A2 = boost::_bi::value<MCServer>; A3 = boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<Connection> >; A4 = boost::arg<1> (*)()]’:
/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:20:59:   required from ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::result_type boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::operator()() [with R = void; F = boost::_mfi::mf3<void, ClientServerManager, const MCServer&, boost::shared_ptr<Connection>&, const boost::system::error_code&>; L = boost::_bi::list4<boost::_bi::value<ClientServerManager*>, boost::_bi::value<MCServer>, boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<Connection> >, boost::arg<1> (*)()>; boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::result_type = void]’
/boost/function/function_template.hpp:153:11:   required from ‘static void boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker0<FunctionObj, R>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&) [with FunctionObj = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf3<void, ClientServerManager, const MCServer&, boost::shared_ptr<Connection>&, const boost::system::error_code&>, boost::_bi::list4<boost::_bi::value<ClientServerManager*>, boost::_bi::value<MCServer>, boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<Connection> >, boost::arg<1> (*)()> >; R = void]’
/boost/function/function_template.hpp:934:60:   required from ‘void boost::function0<R>::assign_to(Functor) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf3<void, ClientServerManager, const MCServer&, boost::shared_ptr<Connection>&, const boost::system::error_code&>, boost::_bi::list4<boost::_bi::value<ClientServerManager*>, boost::_bi::value<MCServer>, boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<Connection> >, boost::arg<1> (*)()> >; R = void]’
/boost/function/function_template.hpp:722:7:   required from ‘boost::function0<R>::function0(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf3<void, ClientServerManager, const MCServer&, boost::shared_ptr<Connection>&, const boost::system::error_code&>, boost::_bi::list4<boost::_bi::value<ClientServerManager*>, boost::_bi::value<MCServer>, boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<Connection> >, boost::arg<1> (*)()> >; R = void; typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type = int]’
/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1071:16:   required from ‘boost::function<R()>::function(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf3<void, ClientServerManager, const MCServer&, boost::shared_ptr<Connection>&, const boost::system::error_code&>, boost::_bi::list4<boost::_bi::value<ClientServerManager*>, boost::_bi::value<MCServer>, boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<Connection> >, boost::arg<1> (*)()> >; R = void; typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type = int]’
../src/ClientServerManager.cpp:90:2:   required from here
/boost/bind/bind.hpp:457:9: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘a[boost::_bi::storage4<A1, A2, A3, boost::arg<I> (*)()>::a4_<boost::_bi::value<ClientServerManager*>, boost::_bi::value<MCServer>, boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<Connection> >, 1>]’
/boost/bind/bind.hpp:457:9: note: candidates are:
In file included ....
/boost/bind/bind.hpp:170:27: note: template<class T> T& boost::_bi::list0::operator[](boost::_bi::value<T>&) const
/boost/bind/bind.hpp:170:27: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included ....
/boost/bind/bind.hpp:457:9: note:   mismatched types ‘boost::_bi::value<T>’ and ‘boost::arg<1>()’
In file included ....
/boost/bind/bind.hpp:172:33: note: template<class T> const T& boost::_bi::list0::operator[](const boost::_bi::value<T>&) const
/boost/bind/bind.hpp:172:33: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included ....
/boost/bind/bind.hpp:457:9: note:   mismatched types ‘const boost::_bi::value<T>’ and ‘boost::arg<1>()’
In file included ....
/boost/bind/bind.hpp:174:27: note: template<class T> T& boost::_bi::list0::operator[](const boost::reference_wrapper<T>&) const
/boost/bind/bind.hpp:174:27: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from ....
/boost/bind/bind.hpp:457:9: note:   mismatched types ‘const boost::reference_wrapper<T>’ and ‘boost::arg<1>()’
In file included from ....
/boost/bind/bind.hpp:176:76: note: template<class R, class F, class L> typename boost::_bi::result_traits<R, F>::type boost::_bi::list0::operator[](boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>&) const
/boost/bind/bind.hpp:176:76: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from ....
/boost/bind/bind.hpp:457:9: note:   mismatched types ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>’ and ‘boost::arg<1>()’
/boost/bind/bind.hpp:178:76: note: template<class R, class F, class L> typename boost::_bi::result_traits<R, F>::type boost::_bi::list0::operator[](const boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>&) const
/boost/bind/bind.hpp:178:76: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/boost/bind/bind.hpp:457:9: note:   mismatched types ‘const boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>’ and ‘boost::arg<1>()’
make: *** [src/ClientServerManager.o] Error 1
```

**A simplified example:**

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/system/error_code.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

class ExampleWorker {
    public:
        void statusPing(boost::function<void()> f){
            // Do work.
            f(); // Call handle
        }
};

class SomeObject {};

void someHandle(boost::shared_ptr<SomeObject> obj,
        const boost::system::error_code& err){
    // ...
}

int main() {
    ExampleWorker* e = new ExampleWorker();
    boost::shared_ptr<SomeObject> ptr(new SomeObject());

    e->statusPing(
            boost::bind(
                &someHandle,
                ptr,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error
            )
    );
}
```

Comment: You're binding all the arguments necessary for invoking `ClientServerManager::onPingCompletion()`, so the callable created from the bind expression will convert to a `boost::function<void()>`. Try making that change to `statusPing()`, and your code should compile.

Comment: Also, those are all compiler errors, not linker errors. Your question is a little confusing at first because you keep mentioning link and linkage errors.

Comment: Thank you @Praetorian for that guidance.  I am still getting an error; would you have any additional advice?   `error: no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘a[boost::_bi::storage4<A1, A2, A3, boost::arg<I> (*)()>::a4_<boost::_bi::value<ClientServerManager*>, boost::_bi::value<MCServer>, boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<Connection> >, 1>]’`

Comment: Could you show the updated code? Note that either `statusPing` must accept `function<void()>`, or you should create a binder that accepts 3 parameters, like `bind(this, _1, _2, _3)` - depending on how you actually intend to invoke that functor.

Comment: Is it the same line that's causing the new error? Can you please try to create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @Praetorian Yes, it appears so.  Take a look at the simplified example I posted.  What silly error am I making?

Comment: Hi, I posted an answer explaining the problem in your simplified example. I know it doesn't solve your original problem, but I'm having trouble understanding the chain of function calls happening in there. Is `onConnect` the asio completion handler function, and you want to pass the error code that the asio operation called `onConnect` with to `statusPing`, and then onto `onPingCompletion`? And I apologize for misleading you earlier, I missed that you were passing `boost::asio::placeholders::error` in the bind arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boost::asio::placeholders::error` is just like using `boost::placeholders::_1` with `boost::bind`, and when you pass a bind expression containing that to an `asio` completion handler function, the function will invoke your handler with the `boost::system::error_code` result from the operation it performed, thus allowing your handler access to the error code.

In your second example, the `boost::function` signature for the following `bind` expression

```
boost::bind(
    &someHandle,
    ptr,
    boost::asio::placeholders::error
)
```

is

```
boost::function<void(boost::system::error_code const&)>
```

To get your code to compile, change the `statusPing()` member function to

```
void statusPing(boost::function<void(boost::system::error_code const&)> f){
    // Do work.
    boost::system::error_code err;
    f(err); // Call handle
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly correct.  I discovered my error after reading more about `boost::bind` last night.  I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527413/how-boostfunction-and-boostbind-work and http://www.radmangames.com/programming/how-to-use-boost-bind to be good resources.